# Can I infer all subsets as frequent from a projection of WiFIsViz?

Tags: data-visualization, association-rules

I am trying to understand what I can infer from a WiFIsViz diagram, where  [WiFIsViz](http://hci.cs.umanitoba.ca/assets/publication_files/2008-DataMining-Leung-WiFizViz.pdf) means Effective Visualization of Frequent Itemsets. Here is a projection of the subsets `acd` and `ce` that I found online.  From the resulting projection, is `ae` reasonable to infer as frequent?

The first filled circle means something that ends in `d` is of equal frequency as something that ends in `e`.  Could not `de` also be frequent in the projection?

[image]